# What is the correct way to show $href = vc_build_link( $href );

Tags: plugins

I want to show wp page bakery addons link to theme elements. I tried this below code but this are not working mine. What is the correct way?

```
<?php
$href = vc_build_link( $content_link ); 

if($href){
   <a href="<?php echo esc_url($href[0]); ?>"></a>
?>

<?php     
}
?>
```